# browser console code to change youtube video quality setting, e.g. from 360p to 144p?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, console

browser console code in the web developer tools (inspect+q in firefox) to send commands to youtube to change the video quality setting, e.g. from 360p to 144p? Is this doable?

Comment: It's not "the same video, at different quality", each quality is literally a different video, so unless you know the exactly URL for the resolution you want: no.

Comment: How do you find out the URL?
I've tried the network monitor in the web dev tools, I got only POST requests all looking the same, googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire= , and a few GET https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/abcdefghijklm/mqdefault_.webp

Comment: look at the active DOM in the inspector, not the network tab.